# D3 difference between ordinal and linear scales

Tags: javascript, d3.js

```
var xScale = d3.scale.ordinal().domain([0, d3.max(data)]).rangeRoundBands([0, w], .1);
var yScale = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, data.length]).range([h, 0]);
```

I'm confused about when to use **ordinal** or **linear** scale in D3.

Below is what I've discovered from the API doc, still bit lost... if anyone can help, it would be much appreciated.

## ordinal(x)

Given a value x in the input domain, returns the corresponding value in the output range.

If the range was specified explicitly (as by range, but not rangeBands, rangeRoundBands or rangePoints), and the given value x is not in the scale’s domain, then x is implicitly added to the domain; subsequent invocations of the scale given the same value x will return the same value y from the range.

## d3.scale.linear()

Constructs a new linear scale with the default domain [0,1] and the default range [0,1]. Thus, the default linear scale is equivalent to the identity function for numbers; for example linear(0.5) returns 0.5.

Comment: The linear scale will interpolate between input values, whereas the ordinal scale will not.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff can you please provide some example?

Comment: There is actually an example for this in the docs, the `linear(0.5)`.

Answer (score 90, accepted):

As for [Ordinal Scales](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Ordinal-Scales):

> Ordinal scales have a **discrete domain**, such as a set of names or categories.
>
> An ordinal scale's values must be coercible to a string, and the stringified version of the domain value uniquely identifies the corresponding range value.

So, as an example, a domain of an ordinal scale may contain names, like so:

```
var ordinalScale = d3.scale.ordinal()
        .domain(['Alice', 'Bob'])
        .range([0, 100]);

ordinalScale('Alice'); // 0
ordinalScale('Bob'); // 100
```

Notice how all values are strings. They cannot be interpolated. What is between 'Alice' and 'Bob'? I don't know. Neither does D3.

Now, as for [Quantitative Scales](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Quantitative-Scales) (e.g. Linear Scales):

> Quantitative scales have a **continuous domain**, such as the set of real numbers, or dates.

As an example, you can construct the following scale:

```
var linearScale = d3.scale.linear()
        .domain([0, 10])
        .range([0, 100]);

linearScale(0); // 0
linearScale(5); // 50
linearScale(10); // 100
```

Notice how D3 is able to interpolate 5 even if we haven't specified it explicitly in the domain.

Take a look at [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t5qdjcgf/) to see the above code in action.

Comment: Omg... you should write the d3 API doc, brilliant, totally make sense. Thanks heaps :)

Comment: If you have more than 2 items in your domain, i.e. `['Alice', 'Bob', 'Carl']` then you may need to use `rangePoints` instead of `range`.

Comment: Can you please explain this without words such as "discrete domain", "quantitative scale", "interpolated", "coercible" and "domain" so us lowly earthlings can understand it? Or at least define them. Not all of us have a mathematical background.

Comment: Hello @dthree, I'm sorry it wasn't clear. These are the terms often used in D3 documentation, and in the API. I assumed that the reader is familiar with their meaning. I don't have a mathematical background either, but reading about [domain of a function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_of_a_function) was a good starting point and helped me a lot in understanding these terms and D3 itself.

Comment: Very helpful, thanks. However it seems D3 _does_ think to know what is between Alice and Bob. For example, AlicePointFive is 0, while AlicePointSeven is 1 (see updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t5qdjcgf/94/)) . Any explanation of the logic behind those attributions?

Answer (score 3):

In D3.js scales transform a number from the domain to the range. For a linear scale the domain will be a continuous variable, with an unlimited range of values, which can be then transformed to a continuous range.  For ordinal scales there will be a discrete domain, for example months of the year where there are limited range of possible values that may be ordered but aren't continuous. The [API docs on Github](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Scales) can probably explain the difference better than I have

Answer (score 3):

OK, we can start learning it with using both with the same data to see differences(I'm using d3 v4), imagine we have the data below with using `ordinal` and `linear` scales:

```
const data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

const scaleLinear = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, Math.max(...data)]).range([1, 100]);

const scaleOrdinal = d3.scaleOrdinal()
  .domain(data).range(['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five']);
```

Now we start calling them to see the result:

```
scaleLinear(1); //20
scaleOrdinal(1); //one

scaleLinear(2); //40
scaleOrdinal(2); //two

scaleLinear(5); //100
scaleOrdinal(5); //five
```

Look at the functions and the results we get, as you see in the ordinal one we map the data to our range, while in the linear one we stretch to the range, so in these cases for example **scaleLinear(1) will return 20**... our domain max is 100 and 100 divided by 5 is equal 20, so **scaleLinear(1)** is **20** and **scaleLinear(2)** is **40**...

But as you see, **scaleOrdinal(1)** is map to the array in the range, so it's equal to **one** and **scaleOrdinal(2)** it's equal to **two**...

So that's how you can use these scales, **scaleLinear** is useful for many things including present the scale on page, but **scaleOrdinal** more useful for getting the data in order, that's how it's explained in the documentation:

> **# d3.scaleLinear() <>**
>
> Constructs a new continuous scale with the unit domain [0, 1], the
>   unit range [0, 1], the default interpolator and clamping disabled.
>   Linear scales are a good default choice for continuous quantitative
>   data because they preserve proportional differences. Each range value
>   y can be expressed as a function of the domain value x: y = mx + b.

> **d3.scaleOrdinal([range]) <>**
>
> Constructs a new ordinal scale with an empty domain and the specified
>   range. If a range is not specified, it defaults to the empty array; an
>   ordinal scale always returns undefined until a non-empty range is
>   defined.

Also this is a good example from d3 in depth using both ordinal and linear scales at the same time:

```js
var myData = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']

var linearScale = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, 11])
  .range([0, 600]);

var ordinalScale = d3.scaleOrdinal()
  .domain(myData)
  .range(['black', '#ccc', '#ccc']);

d3.select('#wrapper')
  .selectAll('text')
  .data(myData)
  .enter()
  .append('text')
  .attr('x', function(d, i) {
    return linearScale(i);
  })
  .text(function(d) {
    return d;
  })
  .style('fill', function(d) {
    return ordinalScale(d);
  });
```

```css
body {
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #333;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.2.2/d3.min.js"></script>

<svg width="800" height="60">
   <g id="wrapper" transform="translate(100, 40)">
   </g>
</svg>
```